# How to extract only text from the div containing more divs using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a div element which contains more child elements. I want to crape only the text from all the child elements of that div. Is there any inbuilt funcion or scrapy property for that.

example : 
I need to scrape the breadcrumb from http://www.jabong.com/z-collection-Olive-Mocassins-376735.html

div id to  scrape content from  : breadcrumbs
Desired Output: Home > Men > Shoes > Casual Shoes > Moccasins > Olive Mocassins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [`HtmlXPathSelector`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#htmlxpathselector-objects) and an XPath expression selecting all descendant text nodes of the `div` with ID "breadcrumbs", such as `id("breadcrumbs")//text()`

To illustrate that, I'll use the `scrapy shell` command, which gives you an `HtmlXPathSelector` instance, `hxs`:

```
paul@wheezy:~$ scrapy shell http://www.jabong.com/z-collection-Olive-Mocassins-376735.html
...
2013-10-15 09:30:06+0200 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.jabong.com/z-collection-Olive-Mocassins-376735.html> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   hxs        <HtmlXPathSelector xpath=None data=u'<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Ty'>
...
In [1]: hxs.select('id("breadcrumbs")//text()').extract()
Out[1]: 
[u'\r\n                                    ',
 u'Home',
 u'\r\n                                                ',
 u'>',
 u'\r\n                                                                                                ',
 u'Men',
 u'\r\n                                                ',
 u'>',
 u'\r\n                                                                                                ',
 u'Shoes',
 u'\r\n                                                ',
 u'>',
 u'\r\n                                                                                                ',
 u'Casual Shoes',
 u'\r\n                                                ',
 u'>',
 u'\r\n                                                                                                ',
 u'Moccasins',
 u'\r\n                                                ',
 u'>',
 u'\r\n                                                                                                ',
 u'Olive Mocassins',
 u'\r\n                                                         \r\n',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n\r\n        ']
```

If you need to strip those whitespace characters, you can use `map()` with `unicode.strip`

```
In [2]: map(unicode.strip, hxs.select('id("breadcrumbs")//text()').extract())
Out[2]: 
[u'',
 u'Home',
 u'',
 u'>',
 u'',
 u'Men',
 u'',
 u'>',
 u'',
 u'Shoes',
 u'',
 u'>',
 u'',
 u'Casual Shoes',
 u'',
 u'>',
 u'',
 u'Moccasins',
 u'',
 u'>',
 u'',
 u'Olive Mocassins',
 u'',
 u'',
 u'']

In [3]:
```

You can remove those empty lines using `filter()`

```
In [4]: filter(bool, map(unicode.strip, hxs.select('id("breadcrumbs")//text()').extract()))
Out[4]: 
[u'Home',
 u'>',
 u'Men',
 u'>',
 u'Shoes',
 u'>',
 u'Casual Shoes',
 u'>',
 u'Moccasins',
 u'>',
 u'Olive Mocassins']

In [5]:
```

Here's a one-liner to get breadcrumbs as a single string, using `str.join()` and `map()` again:

```
In [9]: ' '.join(map(unicode.strip, hxs.select('id("breadcrumbs")//text()').extract())).strip()
Out[9]: u'Home  >  Men  >  Shoes  >  Casual Shoes  >  Moccasins  >  Olive Mocassins'
```

or even:

```
In [10]: ' '.join(filter(bool, map(unicode.strip, hxs.select('id("breadcrumbs")//text()').extract())))
Out[10]: u'Home > Men > Shoes > Casual Shoes > Moccasins > Olive Mocassins'
```

Comment: thats what i was looking for... Is there a direct function to jin all the array elements and to get output like  Home > Men > Shoes > Casual Shoes > Moccasins > Olive Mocassins .. or should I loop through and concatenate

Comment: @user2129794, I update my answer with a solution to that using `.join()`